# Implement Observer Pattern Android

Tags: java, android

I want to execute a method from the MainActivity class when a variable from a non-activity class has changed its state. So I thought i could use the so called Observer Pattern.

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
private ExpandableListViewAdapter mExpandableListViewAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initViews();
    initListeners();
    initObjects();
    initListData();
}

 public void update(){
    mExpandableListViewAdapter.setSelectedChild(-1);
    mExpandableListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Non-activity class:

```
public class MSG0100  implements PreselectionAplicationUseCases {
    msg100PreselectionAplication=true;

 public boolean isMsg100PreselectionAplication() {
    return msg100PreselectionAplication;
}

public void setMsg100PreselectionAplication(boolean msg100PreselectionAplication) {
    this.msg100PreselectionAplication = msg100PreselectionAplication;
}
}
```

I want to execute update method from MainActivity class when msg100PreselectionAplication changes.

In my case MSG0100 it's my Subject class that it updates the variable msg100PreselectionAplication, and the MainActivity class it's an concrete observer, and usually you have to create the Observer class, but my problem is that the MainActivity has to extend from that class and that's a problem because Java does not support multiple inheritance. Any solution to that problem?

Comment: And you didn't find a single article or tutorial online to get you started?

Comment: Yes i did. In my case MSG0100 it's my Subject class that it updates the variable msg100PreselectionAplication, and the MainActivity class it's an concrete observer, and usually you have to create the Observer class, but my problem is that the MainActivity has to extend from that class and that's a problem because Java does not support multiple inheritance.

Comment: Then add that explanation to the question